# iOS running multiple operations in a thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, nsoperationqueue

I am new to threads in iOS Development, i have question here consider the following code

```
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];
   [self startAnewOperationInSepThread];
   [self startAnotherOperationInSepThread];
```

My understanding here is when the first line is executed the activity indicator will be started in the main thread. So now the main thread is responsible for running the activity indicator. How the subsequent Operations will be invoked.

Comment: do you want to access activityIndicator from other threads ?

Comment: The above code works fine, the activity indicator is animating and other subsequent operations are called but i am not clear how the two methods are called because the main thread is now handling the activity indicator there is no way to call the other two methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When the first line is executed the activity indicator is not started. It will be started as soon as your method in main thread invoked by main loop ends. While your method is running in main thread, nothing will change for UI.

Answer (score 1):

use  `performSelectorInBackground`

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourmethod:) withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you call [activityIndicator startAnimating]; from main thread, that is just a call to start the animation. The actual animation is done on a separate thread.

even-though the activity indicator is still animation, **that does not mean** you cannot do anything on main thread. Because his duty (calling the startAnimating method) is over.

After calling startAnimating on activityIndicator, it jumps to the next line and execute [self myMethod1]; then [self myMethod2]; for the following code.

Don't make them complicated, That is this simple

```
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];
   [self myMethod1];
   [self myMethod2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to options for it

1.> You can run both two methods on different - different threads like it

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnewOperationInSepThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnotherOperationInSepThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

OR

2.> if you want that after on thread has completed another will start then first call startAnewOperationInSepThread method and inside it's definition call startAnotherOperationInSepThread like it

```
-(void)startAnotherOperationInSepThread
{
    [self startAnotherOperationInSepThread];
}
```

Please let me know if still u are facing any problem. Thanks